# (DJANGO) How to be redirect to another URL from a view?

Tags: python, django, spotify

I'm new to Django and now I'm getting some problems in redirecting to another URL from the current view. In this case I'd like to be redirect to the  Spotify Login page.

Here's my view:

```
#############################################################################
client_id = 'somestring'; # Your client id
client_secret = 'anotherstring'; # Your secret
redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/'; # Your redirect uri
stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state'
#############################################################################

def generateRandomString(length):
    text = ''
    possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

    for i in range(0,length):
         text += possible[math.floor(random.random() * len(possible))] 
    return text

##############################################################################


def login_process(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        state = generateRandomString(16)
        print(str(state))
        HttpResponse.set_cookie(stateKey, state)

        #your application requests authorization
        scope = 'user-top-read user-read-email'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request, 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + urllib.parse.urlencode({
          response_type: 'code',
          client_id: client_id,
          scope: scope,
          redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
          state: state
        }), {})

def login_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    #return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello world</h1>")
    return render(request, "login.html", {})




def callback_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "callback.html", {})
```

here's the link I should click to be redirect:

```
    <a href="login/">Login with spotify</a>
```

here's my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', login_view, name='login_view'),
    path('login/', login_process, name = 'login'),
    path('callback/', callback_view, name = 'callback_view'),
]
```

The error I get is "AttributeError at /login/'str' object has no attribute 'cookies' " and I don0t even know if the method "return HttpResponseRedirect" is the right way to do all these things. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
HttpResponse.set_cookie(stateKey, state)
```

You are calling `HttpResponse.set_cookie` on the class itself, not on an instance, so you get an unbound method which expects an instance as first parameter. The proper way is actually to first instanciate the response, then call `set_cookie` on it:

```
qs = urllib.parse.urlencode({
          "response_type": 'code',
          "client_id": client_id,
          "scope": scope,
          "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
          "state": state
        })
url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?{}'.format(qs) 
response = HttpResponseRedirect(request, url)
reponse.set_cookie(whatever)
return response
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I still get an error when I log in, it says "Exception Type: NameError at /login/
Exception Value: name 'response_type' is not defined"

Comment: @DvD_95 the quotes around the dict keys were missing indeed (fixed) - but that was already the case in your original snippet (which I copy/pasted). Also note that this is typically the kind of trivial errors any dev should be able to spot and fix by themselves...

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I know, I figured it out after some debugging, it couldn't be than that at some point! Hahah